# Does grappling a prone creature effectively create the restrained condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, prone, melee-combat

I need some clarification. I’m playing a barbarian (5e), Path of the Storm Wielder (Journey to Ragnarok) level 5 as of now. If he uses an attack action to shove an opponent prone (and wins the strength check) then with his second attack successfully grapples the now prone opponent, the opponent now has zero movement and can’t get up. Is this correct? I’m want to play this character as more of a Marvel Comics superhero and use grappling, jumping and climbing.

Comment: It's a little confusing that the title question isn't the one you actually end your post with. Yes, you understand correctly, but it doesn't create the restrained condition, effectively or actually. Do you want an answer to the 'is this restrained'? part as well?

Comment: Sorry for the way I phrased the question. I wasn’t sure how to word it. I have since learned about the differences between the two and it’s a significant difference. Always learning. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 10):

### The target of this combo can't stand up, but is not restrained.

You stated the case correctly: [being grappled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Grappled) reduces the target's speed to zero, and the [rules about being prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BeingProne) say

> and a creature can't stand up from prone when its speed is zero.

(Annoyingly, this is not recapitulated in the Prone condition listing.)

However that is not the Restrained condition, functionally or actually.

The effect of [Prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Prone) is, movement limits aside:

> - The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls.
> - An attack roll against the creature has advantage if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. Otherwise, the attack roll has disadvantage.

[Restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained), aside from movement limits, says:

> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.
> - The creature has disadvantage on Dexterity saving throws.

So the two differences are ranged attacks (at disadvantage with prone, at advantage with restrained) and Dexterity saving throws (normal if prone, at disadvantage if restrained).

Comment: Another difference between "prone and grappled" vs. "restrained" is that "grappled" _as a condition_ specifies how to end it (incapacitate the grappler, forced move beyond the reach of the grappler), whereas _restrained as a condition_ does _not_ indicate how to end it.  One presumes that any effect that imposes the restrained condition would give its own, idiosyncratic, method for ending the condition.